# Finding source of $item reference in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, variables

I have the following code that produces the output of the attribute filter in layered - as well as the name of the attribute it also produces the count of products associated with the specific attribute.

I am trying to remove the count next to each attribute (e.g. T-Shirts (1), Shorts (2) etc.). But I cannot for the life of me figure out where the $item phtml is being sourced.

**FILTER_ATTRIBUTE.PHTML**

```
<?php 
$items        = $this->getFiltersArray();
$displayStyle = $this->getColumnsNum(); 
?>


    <ol>
    <?php if ($displayStyle <=1): // one column ?>
        <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>

            <li><?php echo $_item?></li>     

        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below files you can easly get the code.

```
span class="count"(getCount() ?>)
```

Go to following paths:
template\catalog\layer
1)List.phtml
2)filter.phtml